# Haskell, write non-string from print

Tags: haskell, input, output

```
s <- readFile $ head aruments
print $ myFoo s
```

`s` is a String. `myFoo` is a `String -> String`

It writes to terminal something like:

```
"['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

What that annoying me is `" "`. Is it possible to write only `['a', 'b', 'c']`? I mean something like in case of interact:

```
interact myFoo
```

writes to terminal only `['a', 'b', 'c']` although `myFoo` returns `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` will always use `show`, which introduces the additional quotes. If you already have a `String`, use `putStrLn` or `putStr`, depending on whether you want to have a newline after putting the `String`.

Comment: So haskell before writes `string` to output removes quotes.

Comment: @J.Doe: I don't quite get what you mean. `print` is `putStrLn . show`, which is _why_ you get the quotes. You just want to __put__ a __str__ ing on the terminal.